# Setting up SSRS 2012?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We're trying to set up an environment to migrate an SSRS 2005 installation to SSRS 2012.  The install of SSRS 2012 appeared to go fine.  I understand that 2012 (well, 2008 +) does not need IIS anymore, that it uses something called HTTP:sys.  Aside from not knowing what HTTP:sys is, I'm fine with it. The new server did not have IIS installed on it when I installed SSRS 2012.  It does now but it is shut off.  So SSRS 2012 is installed and configured according to the prompts (and a Youtube tutorial and a comparison to how our SSRS 2005 is configured) and it all seems straight forward and should "just work".  But when I follow the URL to the Report manager, I'm prompted for network credentials and then get a blank webpage, not the following as expected (except empty of course):

[image]

Comment: Can you go to RS log folder and check what happened? it is usually at MSRS11.MSSQLSever/Reporting Services/LogFiles.

Comment: I took a look at the last one generated and only found one warning message:  WARN: Initializing UrlRoot to default value of ''  because it was incorrectly specified in Configuration file as ''.  All of the other entries were INFO.  Nothing stood out.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this one before on an install of SSRS 2008R2.

- Open the rsreportserver.config(By default, it can be found from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer)
- Comment out the `<RSWindowsNegotiate/>` under `<AuthenticationTypes>` element.

[Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-windows-authentication-on-the-report-server#proxyfirewallRSWindowsNegotiate)